# Clojure generic "replace" function for vectors

Tags: vector, clojure, replace

I want to know how to, in **Clojure**, if handed a **symbol name** and a **vector**, to replace said item.

For instance, I want to replace any instance of:

```
[:not :symbolName]
```

with

```
(not symbolName)
```

So:

```
[ [:p] [:not :q] [:not :r] [r] ]
```

Would become:

```
[ [:p] (not q) (not r) [r] ]
```

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated, much love in advance ^_^

Answer (score 0):

This is *pretty* generic.

```
(defn sym-replace [[x y] & syms]
  (cond 
    (and x y (some #{x} syms)) (list (-> x name symbol) (-> y name symbol))
    (and x y) [x y]
    :else [x]))
```

Examples:

```
(def my-vec [[:p] [:not :q] [:not :r] ['r] [:foo :bar]])

(map #(sym-replace % :not) my-vec)
;; ([:p] (not q) (not r) [r] [:foo :bar])

(map #(sym-replace % :foo) my-vec)
;; ([:p] [:not :q] [:not :r] [r] (foo bar))

(map #(sym-replace % :not :foo) my-vec)
;; ([:p] (not q) (not r) [r] (foo bar))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(use '[clojure.walk :only (prewalk)])

(defn match? [x]
  (and (vector? x)
       (= (first x) :not)
       (keyword? (second x))))

(defn transform [x]
  (map (comp symbol name) x))

(defn replac [p t x]
 (prewalk #(if (p %) (t %) %) x))

(replac match? transform [[:p] [:not :q] [:not :r] '[r]])
=> [[:p] (not q) (not r) [r]]
```